# Noob: new to bitcoin, bitcoind will not run on Windows 10

Tags: bitcoind, windows

I just heard about Bitcoin, it looks huge, and am trying to get it to work and see how it works.

I live in a very rural community and we do not have Internet yet, I had to do some dirty deeds to get my first minimal hardware, and to get this far to simply post.

--
I installed QT and let it sync.
I want to learn how to run bitcoind on my local Windows PC and issue commands in hex to the network.

### I can't get bitcoind to run.

C:\bitcoin-0.17.0\bin\bitcoind -daemon -datadir=c:\bitcoin          ( when I ran QT, I added -datadir=c:\bitcoin )
Error: -daemon is not supported on this operating system

--
I am assuming I can't or should not run Bitcoin QT and the daemon at the same time.  I'm trying to understand the bitcoin commands, from the command line (not the QT console) and believe that I can not run both at the same time, because both try to sync the blockchain, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can run bitcoind.exe on windows if you leave off the `-daemon` flag, as the error message says. Then it will run in the command prompt window or whatever you are running it with. While it's running, you can interact with it using bitcoin-cli.exe in a separate command prompt window.

No, you can't run bitcoind and bitcoin-qt at the same time if they're using the same data/wallet directory, correct. But that's not the cause of the error here.